# do-while loop not terminate when answer no

Tags: java, arrays, object, format, do-while

```
package homework4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog4 {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            CreditCardNumber[] cred1;
            CreditCardNumber cred2 = getInput();
            Display("The complete number from your input:", cred2);
            cred1 = getInputArray();
            DisplayArray(cred1);
            TryAnother(cred1);
    }

    public static CreditCardNumber getInput() {
        String ID;
        String accNum;
        CreditCardNumber tempCred;      
        System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
        ID = scanner.next();
        System.out.printf("Please enter account number:");
        accNum = scanner.next();
        tempCred = new CreditCardNumber(ID, accNum);
        return tempCred;
    }

    public static void Display(String ch, CreditCardNumber cred2) {
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println(cred2.toString().replaceAll(".{4}", "$0   "));       
}

public static CreditCardNumber[] getInputArray() {
    CreditCardNumber[] tempArray;
    String tempID;
    int size;       
    System.out.printf("Please enter size of the aray:");
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    if(size < 1) {
        size = 1;
    }
    tempArray = new CreditCardNumber[size];
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    tempID = scanner.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = new CreditCardNumber();
        tempArray[i].CreateCred(tempID);
    }
    return tempArray;
}

public static void DisplayArray(CreditCardNumber[] cred1) {
    for(int i = 0; i< cred1.length; i++) {
        Display("Credit Card # " + i+":" + '\n', cred1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean TryAnother(CreditCardNumber[] cred1) {
    String s;
    System.out.printf("Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):");
    s = scanner.next();
    if(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n') {
        do {
                TryAnother(cred1);
                cred1 = getInputArray();
                DisplayArray(cred1);                
            } while(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n');      
    }
    return false;   
}
}
```

Hi, I have a problem in my `do-while` loop in `TryAnother` method, I'm trying to get the code to repeat for some reason when I enter no the process does not terminate when the condition of the `do while` loop said it should terminate also it repeat the line that tell user to enter 'yes' or 'no'.

something like:

```
Please enter issuer ID:321321 
Please enter account number:654654654 
The complete number from your input: 
3213 2165 4654 6549
Please enter size of the aray:7 
Please enter issuer ID:789789 
Credit Card # 0:
7897 8985 6852 9257
Credit Card # 1:
7897 8917 0678 9958
Credit Card # 2:
7897 8900 5781 0934
Credit Card # 3:
7897 8949 2244 6098
Credit Card # 4:
7897 8941 3828 4895
Credit Card # 5:
7897 8965 9233 5006
Credit Card # 6:
7897 8981 8442 5880
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):n
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):n
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):no
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):
```

As you can see when I enter no. it keeps repeating the same sentence. What I want is for it to repeat from enter the array size sentence, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    }while(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n');
```

to:

```
    }while(s.charAt(0) != 'N' && s.charAt(0) != 'n');
```

Comment: Thank you, how could i forget that